# PyCharm safe delete function

Tags: pycharm, refactoring

There is a "safe delete" feature in PyCharm which shows you all usages of a file before you delete it.

I want to safely delete a single function in PyCharm, is there any way to do this without manually looking for usages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the kind of functionality you're asking for exists exactly, but if the issue you're facing is that you don't want to hit ctrl+shift+f every time you're deleting a function, what you could do is ctrl + left click the function signature instead.

Assuming there's no usages, PyCharm will let you know

[image]

Alternatively if there are usages, you will get to know this as well.

[image]

Personally I would still search with ctrl+shift+f, as PyCharm's usage search isn't always 100% accurate, especially in projects that rely on duck typing.

Comment: I'm using the Ctrl+click method already but I'll accept that there is no other way right now :) Thanks